# Error while trying to write the result of WCC search on an excel using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache, oracle-ucm

I am trying to write the response of GET_SEARCH_RESULTS of WCC on an excel file using apache poi 3.15.But I am getting the following error here.

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/multimap/ArrayListValuedHashMap
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.commons.collections4.multimap.ArrayListValuedHashMap`

I have already included the following jar in the library path.

```
$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/poi-3.15.jar;
$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/poi-ooxml-3.15.jar;
$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar;
$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/poi-scratchpad-3.15.jar;
$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar;
$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/commons-collections4-4.1.jar;
$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar;
$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar;
$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;
$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/commons-io-1.3.2.jar.
```

It seems that my WCC (11.1.1.8) is not able to load the class file from commons-collections4-4.1.jar.

I have extracted the ArrayListValuedHashMap.class from the collections jar and added that to the classpath but that did not help either.

Do I need to try with lower versions of POI?

Thanks in advance,
Ananda Roy

Comment: Linking to cross-post on Oracle forum: https://community.oracle.com/people/Ananda+Roy/status/59700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Jonathan,

We need to provide the jars using the classes folder and not using the lib folder.

This has resolved the issue.

classpath=$COMPONENT_DIR/classes;$COMPONENT_DIR/classes/itextpdf-5.5.6.jar;$COMPONENT_DIR/classes/bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar;

Answer (score 0):

Is the JAR specified on the *classpath* variable in the component manifest file? Do not use the *libpath* variable.

```
classpath=$COMPONENT_DIR/classes;$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/itextpdf-5.5.6.jar;$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar;
```

A full example can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/jhult/pdfpagenumbers/src/6f039c1a711ed7f5bb9fac7ed8b958c38110eae8/PDFPageNumbers.hda?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).

Comment: Thank you Jonathan.I have used both classpath and libpath variables.With your suggestion,I have removed the entries from libpath,build the component,restarted the servers.However,the issue still exists. am attaching my component.hda file here for reference.

Comment: @Properties LocalData
ComponentName=E**
blDateFormat=dd/MM/yyyy {H:mm[:ss] [zzz]}!tAsia/Calcutta
classpath=$COMPONENT_DIR/classes;$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/poi-3.15.jar;$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/poi-ooxml-3.15.jar;$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar;$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/poi-scratchpad-3.15.jar;$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar;$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/commons-collections-3.1.jar;$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar;$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/commons-io-1.3.2.jar;$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/ArrayListValuedHashMap.class;$COMPONENT_DIR/lib/commons-collections4-4.0.jar

Comment: Could not add total contents of my component.hda file.